# python Aggregate (groupby) 2d-matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have a square array/matrix of data (roughly 2000 rows and columns)
and I want to aggregate it into a smaller array (roughly 1000 rows and columns)

I have a list of main_ids, which corresponds to the rows/columns in the orriginal array.
e.g. new_ids = [0,0,0,1,1,2,...] would send aggregate the first 3 rows/columns to new row/column 1, and then the 4th,5th row/column aggregated to the 2nd and so on...

So far I have the following code but I would like to optomize it if possible

```
import numpy as np
new_ids = np.array(new_ids)
unew_ids = unique(new_ids)
unew_ids.sort()

#Collapse rows
rowMat = np.zeros([len(new_ids),len(unew_ids)], dtype=np.float64)

for i in range(0,len(mat[0])):
    for j in range(0, len(unew_ids)):
        rowMat[i,j] = np.sum(mat[i][new_ids == unew_ids[j]])

#Collapse columns
outMat = np.zeros([len(unew_ids),len(unew_ids)], dtype=np.float64)

for i in range(0, len(unew_ids)):
    for j in range(0, len(unew_ids)):
        outMat[j,i] = np.sum(rowMat[:,i][new_ids == unew_ids[j]])

return outMat
```

I have tried experimenting with matplotlib.mlab.rec_groupby, however for that I need (or I think I need) to build a new array of (new_ids, row) where row is a numpy array with a row from the orriginal matrix, however that doesn't seem to work.

[Edit:]

As an added problem, I'm not actually doing a sum when I aggregate, I'm doing a custom function that needs all the numbers at once (doing it by rows and then columns wasn't working)

{roughly - my_function = (take sum of elements, if any were negative remove those from sum and then mulitply the whole thing by 1/(1+sum of negative elements))}

I think what I need to do is:

```
outputmat = [ [my_function(input_mat[new_ids_arr == tuple])] for tuple in unique_arr.ravel()]

outputmat = np.array(outputmat)
outputmat.reshape(something)
```

where new_ids_arr is an array of the form [[(10,10),(10,10),...][(10,10),(10,10),(10,12),...],...] - i.e. tuples of where everything is going post aggregation.
I'm hoping I can find a funciton (or build one) that does new_ids_arr = new_ids * new_ids^Transpose ... or similar

unique_arr = is an array of the same size/shape as output, and with each element containing a tuple (e.g. unique_arr[0,0] = (10,10)  meaing take put all the input_matrix elements that where in a place flagged as 10,10 into this location).

Any thoughts?
Particularly on how I could easily build an array of tuples given a list?

Comment: As an added problem, I'm not actually doing a sum when i aggregate, I'm doing a custom function that needs all the numbers at once (doing it by rows and then columns wasn't working)

Comment: I think what I need to do is:
from the new_ids - make a 'matrix' where each element is a tuple point to the location of where the aggregation will take it.

e.g. new_ids = [10,10,12,5,5,..] then new_ids_mat = [[(10,10),(10,10),....],[(10,10),(12,10),....]..]
I want new_ids_mat = (new_ids * new_ids^T) or something... hopefully there is a function I can use..

then I do the same with my list of unique_new_ids - [[10,10),(10,5),...]].

Then something like
unique_new_ids_r = unique_new_ids.ravel()
output = [ [my_func(input_mat[new_ids_mat[tuple]]) ] for tuple in unique_new_ids_r]

sound right?

Answer (score 2):

If you can convert your `new_ids` to something like `[0,3,5,...]` then you could try something like this:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
arr = np.random.rand(20,20)

rowidx = np.array([0, 3, 9, 12, 18], dtype=np.int32)
colidx = np.array([0, 5, 10, 15], dtype=np.int32)

#Collapse rows
step1 = np.add.reduceat(arr, rowidx, axis=0)

#Collapse columns
step2 = np.add.reduceat(step1, colidx, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks,
I'm not sure if I can reduce my new_ids to a set of slices or not.
Maybe. I'll have a play

Comment: Useful info thanks, Unfortunately my problem requires aggregating both the rows and columns at the same time. See edit to question.